# Find and fix an error in the factorial program (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I have such a problem: Find and fix the error in the program for finding the factorial.

And here is the code:

```
var counter = prompt("Enter the number");
var factorial = 1;

document.write("Factorial of a number: " + counter + "! = ");

do {

     if (counter == 0) {
                factorial = 1;
                break;
     }

     factorial = factorial / counter;
     counter = counter + 1;
}
while (counter > 0);

document.write(factorial);
```

The tooltips say that something is wrong with the factorial variable itself, but I can't see anything. I have tried different options, including writing `factorial = factorial * counter;` instead of `factorial = factorial / counter;`,but it's for sure something else.

As well, most probably the while loop is endless, because of this condition while (counter > 0).

Comment: Uhh the concept of factorial is about a product of numbers, like 1*2*3*4 etc. There is no multiplication in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion on how to fix it

```
var counter = 5
var factorial = 1;
if (counter === 0) {
console.log(factorial);
} else {
  while (counter > 0) {
    factorial *= counter;
    counter--;
  }
  console.log(factorial);
}
```

I just replaced the document.write with console.log

The logic that i modified is that to compute the factorial you just multiply
n*(n-1)*(n-2)*....*(1) so the counter is updated

1. so counter shoudld be decremented
2. factorial should be multiplied not divided

Comment: Unfortunately, the system still gives an error :( But anyway, thank you very much for your help!